# Why is there no (tame) knot group has a presentation with deficiency two

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, group-presentation, low-dimensional-topology

I am recently reading Rolfsen's Knots and Links, 3E6 says there is no (tame) knot group which has a presentation with deficiency two, and I am wondering why.

What I know:

1. Every tame knot group (in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $S^3$) has a finite presentation of deficiency one, by Wirtinger presentation.
2. The abelianization of each knot group is infinite cyclic, by either Wirtinger presentation for tame knots or abelianizing it to get $H_1$ and apply Mayor-Vietorus.

My question is pretty simple:
Intuitively with each one of the relation in a group presentation, we can get rid of one generator at most, so abelianizing a finite group presentation can reduce the number of generators by at most the number of the relations. Since this gives $\mathbb{Z}$, we have the deficiency of any presentation of the knot group at most one. How can I make this rigorous though?

Thanks in advance for helpful ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the main idea, so I'll just explain how you might make it rigorous.  Suppose you have a presentation $G=\langle g_1,\dots,g_n \mid r_1,\dots,r_m\rangle$ and want to compute the abelianization.  First, a group presentation is the same as writing a group as sequence
$$F_m \xrightarrow{\phi} F_n \to G \to 1$$
where $F_m$ and $F_n$ are free groups of orders $m$ and $n$, respectively, with the property that $F_n$ surjects onto $G$ and the normal closure of the image of $F_m$ is the kernel of $F_n\to G$.  If we write $x_1,\dots,x_m$ for the generators of $F_m$, then we define $\phi(x_i)=r_i$.  Now, we want to compute the abelianization.  The abelianization functor is right exact, so applying it to this sequence we get a sequence
$$\mathbb{Z}^m \xrightarrow{\phi_*} \mathbb{Z}^n \to \operatorname{Ab}G \to 0$$
that one can check is exact, where if $e_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{Z}^m$ with a $1$ in position $i$, then $\phi_*(e_i)$ is a vector that gives a signed count of how many times each generator appears in $\phi(x_i)$.  For example, if $r_2=g_1g_2g_1g_2^{-1}$ and $n=3$, then $\phi_*(e_2)=(2,0,0)$.
In particular, $\phi_*$ can be written as an $n\times m$ matrix with values in $\mathbb{Z}$, and then we get that $\operatorname{Ab}G$ is the cokernel of this matrix.

This next bit is essentially using the structure theorem for modules over a PID.  A useful tool is Smith Normal Form: there exist automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that the matrix for $\phi_*$ is diagonal and each diagonal entry is divisible by the next.  Once it is in this form, the number of all-zero rows gives you the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ factors.  If $n\geq m+2$, then there *must* be at least two $\mathbb{Z}$ factors.  As you pointed out, knot groups have only one $\mathbb{Z}$ factor.  To tie these together, we need to say that the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ factors is well-defined.

One trick is to tensor everything with $\mathbb{Q}$.  Tensoring is right exact, so we get a presentation for $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \operatorname{Ab}(G)$:
$$\mathbb{Q}^m \xrightarrow{\phi_{**}} \mathbb{Q}^n \to \mathbb{Q}\otimes \operatorname{Ab}(G) \to 0$$
The matrix for this presentation is given by normalizing all the nonzero entries on the diagonal to $1$ (since we can divide in $\mathbb{Q}$!).  Thus, the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \operatorname{Ab}(G)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the number of nonzero rows in the matrix, and since dimension is well defined, so is the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ factors.

Comment: The sequence $F_m \xrightarrow{\phi} F_n \to G \to 1$ is not exact. To get an exact sequence you need to replace $F_m$ by the subgroup of $F_n$ that is normally generated by the words $r_1,...,r_m$, and which is usually an infinite rank free group --- in fact the kernel of $F_n \mapsto G$ is finitely generated if and only if it has finite index (and so $G$ is finite) or trivial (and so $G$ is free).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the need to take a normal closure.

Comment: That helps a lot! One more question @Kyle Miller, since to get an ES, we have to replace $F_m$ by the normal closure of its image, the right exactness of Abel functor can't be directly applied here. How should we modify the argument? I was thinking if we can keep the non-ES, but add the kernel $K$ as $F_m\xrightarrow{\phi_k}K\xrightarrow{\iota}F_n\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1$, where $\iota$ the inclusion map and $\iota\circ\phi_k = \phi$. Now abelianize it, and we should get an ES from $K$ to the right. Now I just want to verify if we get $\mathbb{Z}_m \cong \text{Ab}(F_m) \cong \text{Ab}(K)$.

Comment: @ShiyuLiang What I had in mind was was that abelianization preserves colimits (for example cokernels), and since $G$ is the cokernel of $\phi$ (which is $F_n$ modulo the normal closure of the image of $\phi$), then the abelianization of $G$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of $\phi_*$.  You can also skip this line of argument and think about what happens to the presentation when you abelianize: by adding in each commutator, you can sort the variables in each relation and represent them as $\mathbb{Z}$-vectors.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've just learned about *coexact* sequences, which seems to be exactly the concept I wanted for what a group presentation is.  The abelianization functor is right coexact, and in abelian categories coexactness = exactness.